# Execute subprocesses in JavaEE 6

Tags: multithreading, subprocess, java-ee-6, application-server

I'm trying to execute subprocesses from within my application server (Glassfish 3.1.2)

Therefore I discovered the Apache Commons Exec library. The problem is that this library creates threads which should not be done on an application server because the server is not aware of these threads.
What could be a solution to this problem?

Would it be possible to create a message component written in Java SE who consumes messages containing information about pending jobs and register it with the application server?

The application server would then not have to deal with runtime exceptions and threads but just consume messages which contain the result or an exception.

Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You could either use:

- [MDB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipko.html) (as pointed by duffymo),
- [Servlets 3.0 asynchronous processing](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html),
- [Asynchronous EJB invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html).

Effectively, it should give you similar functionality as plain subprocesses.

Using Java SE component which communicates with Java EE just to overcome using threads on your own sounds a bit like an overkill. Just read about mentioned solutions and try if any of them fits your needs.

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to use a library (apache commons exec) which depends on threads. Your solution suggests would only apply if I created such a library on my own but I'm trying to port it to the use in an application server

Comment: So you're porting an Java SE application that uses apache commons exec or you're writing your application and you need threading? If it's the former case, you can either violate the specification or use the solution you proposed in the post.

Comment: My external library uses threads and I use my external library within my application server -> so I use threads in my application server. I suppose if I use an EJB and asynchronously call a library method which uses threads then this makes no difference because the application server is still not aware of the (by the library created) thread and therefore can't manage it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make any difference - the solutions I posted in the answer was 'how to deal with threads in application server'. You'll still have the same problem, but as far as I know it's "forbidden" to spawn and control threads but I don't think the app-server won't let you to do it. In other words - it violates the specs but it should be doable... If you say it's not than unfortunately I don't know how to solve your problem :-(

Comment: Yes you are right in that it is generally possible. I guess I'm going to violate the spec then. Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: polofan - did you manage to solve your problem? Recently I've bumped into EE concurrency utilities specification that might be interesting for you: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/concurrency_utilities-1_0-edr-spec/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Message driven beans were designed for asynchronous processing.  It could be a solution to your problem.  You can create a separate listener thread pool sized to handle the traffic.